# How at add system property in Android

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm trying to add system properties that will be available for 'adb' access.

Following this thread:
[How to add new System Properties in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736862/how-to-add-new-system-properties-in-java)

I tried doing the following:

```
System.setProperty("TEST", "test");
String prop = (System.getProperty("TEST"));
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, prop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The last line displays a good result (I see a Toast with "test") so I know that the property was set properly.

When I try to access the same property for adb, I get a null value:

adb shell

> getprop TEST

(response is empty)
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Can you show code for access the same property for adb?

Comment: What do you get when you try adb shell getprop (this should view all the properties) ? without supplying it a param. Can you also try to adb shell stop and adb shell start and then do adb shell getprop param.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, In general, this is the code I'm trying to do:
adb shell getprop TEST
Example:

C:\Users\Amir>adb shell getprop TEST


C:\Users\Amir>

As you can see, the result is empty.

I'm also trying:

C:\Users\Amir>adb shell setprop my.test 1234

C:\Users\Amir>adb shell getprop my.test


C:\Users\Amir>

This also fails.